# Trying to plot two or more infrastructures in the same figure using OSMnx

Tags: python, plot, openstreetmap, networkx

I'm trying to plot multiple infrastructure networks(for example streets, rails and buildings) in the same figure using OSMnx but not really having success.

This is one of my attempts:

```
import osmnx as ox
dist = 2000
point = (41.877092, -87.628)
north, south, east, west = ox.bbox_from_point(point, distance=dist)
bbox_proj = ox.bbox_from_point(point, dist, project_utm=True)
streets = ox.core.osm_net_download(
    north=north,
    south=south,
    east=east,
    west=west,
    infrastructure='way["highway"]'
    )
railways = ox.core.osm_net_download(
    north=north,
    south=south,
    east=east,
    west=west,
    infrastructure='way["railway"]'
    )
buildings = ox.core.osm_net_download(
    north=north,
    south=south,
    east=east,
    west=west,
    infrastructure='way["building"]'
    )
streets[0]['elements'] = streets[0]['elements'] + railways[0]['elements'] + buildings[0]['elements']
net = streets
G = ox.core.create_graph(net)
G = ox.truncate_graph_bbox(G, north, south, east, west, truncate_by_edge=True)
G = ox.project_graph(G)
_, _ = ox.plot.plot_graph(G, bbox=bbox_proj, fig_height=10, node_size=0, edge_color='black', edge_linewidth=0.5, save=True)
```

Result of this code is only ploting the first 2 infrastructures, streets and rails, but not buildings:

[image]
Result of ox.plot_figure_ground (only plots streets infrastructure):

[image]
Buildings data is being downloaded despite not being plotted(**I know about plot_buildings but I don't want colored buildings, just lines**).

Before this I was trying to find a way to add multiple filters all at once in the `infrastructure` parameter. Something like:

```
nets = ox.core.osm_net_download(
    north=north,
    south=south,
    east=east,
    west=west,
    infrastructure='way["highway"],way["railway"],way["buildings"]'
    )
```

But not sure if this is possible.

Any way to plot more than two of them in one figure and, if posible, concisely in OSMnx?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, and this will do it concisely:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# get graphs of different infrastructure types, then combine
place = 'Berkeley, California, USA'
G1 = ox.graph_from_place(place, custom_filter='["highway"~"residential"]')
G2 = ox.graph_from_place(place, custom_filter='["railway"~"rail"]')
G = nx.compose(G1, G2)

# get building footprints
fp = ox.footprints_from_place(place)

# plot highway edges in yellow, railway edges in red
ec = ['y' if 'highway' in d else 'r' for _, _, _, d in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)]
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor='k', edge_color=ec,
                        node_size=0, edge_linewidth=0.5,
                        show=False, close=False)

# add building footprints in 50% opacity white
fp.plot(ax=ax, color='w', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: OSMnx streets, railway, and buildings plotted together]

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883614/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720802/7321942

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `buildings` with `building`. The correct OSM key is [`building`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building) without an "s" at the end. In fact, most OSM keys are singular.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Just a typo when I tried to make the code more organized for the question. Thanks though!