# Download OSM network (with OSMNx) filtering based on the union of tag values

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I would like to download a network from OSM with union of 2 filters based on highway and cycleway tags.

```
    network=ox.core.graph_from_place ( place_name, custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]["bicycle"!~"no”]’
```

This command makes the intersection of the 2 filters. So it gets all edges with highway = cycleway, and with cycleway tag different from value “no”.

However if I would like to make the union with the filter `["cycleway”~"lane”]` I don’t know the boolean ‘OR’ operatore for OSM.

I tried the following but it doesn’t work:

```
    network=ox.core.graph_from_place ( place_name, custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]["bicycle"!~"no”] or ["cycleway”~"lane”]’

    network=ox.core.graph_from_place ( place_name, custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]["bicycle"!~"no”] | ["cycleway”~"lane”]’
```

Is there an easy way to write the custom filter making the union of tag values? or should I download more than I need and then remove out edges as suggested in [#151](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/151) ?

Comment: See answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239377/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720802/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883614/7321942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I extract networks based on union of infrastructure filters.

```
# get graphs of different infrastructure types, then combine
place = 'Berkeley, California, USA'
G1 = ox.graph_from_place(place, custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]')
G2 = ox.graph_from_place(place, custom_filter='["cycleway”~"lane”]')
G = nx.compose(G1, G2)
```

Answer (score 1):

osmnx uses Overpass API for downloading OSM data. [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL) has no `or` operator in the way you are trying to use it. There is a simple [union statement](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Union) which just means "download X, then download Y" (see an [example at overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/K5M) for "`highway=cycleway` or `cycleway=lane`"). I guess you have to do the same in osmnx.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, I didn't know about overpass-Turbo. I still haven't solved the problem though.. the question is how to incorporate Overpass queries in OSMNx? 

I discovered there is a function in OSMnx to create a networkx graph from Overpass API HTTP response objects. However, I am not expert in overpass response objects. It would help if someone could provide me with an example of how to use osmnx.core.create_graph.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with OSMNx.