# OSMnx : how to provide more complex feature into the custom_filter parameter

Tags: osmnx

I would like to pass some overpass request into `ox.graph_from_place`, but I don't really understand how it works with the doc.

I would like to create a graph with 2 types of roads (where the buses can pass and where the psv can pass too)

Am'i obliged to join my 2 graphs ? Or Is there a more direct method ?

```
G1 = ox.graph_from_place('Marseille, France', retain_all=True, custom_filter='["bus"="yes"]')

G2 = ox.graph_from_place('Marseille, France', retain_all=True, custom_filter='["psv"="yes"]')

Gtot = nx.disjoint_union(G1,G2)
```

Does someone know the answer?

Have a good day

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. Why not? What happens? What should happen instead?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do from your question. There are many usage examples on GitHub, as linked in the OSMnx documentation: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v0.14.0/notebooks/08-custom-filters-infrastructure.ipynb

Comment: thank you for your answer, i've completed a little my description then. In the doc, then I only see that you can pass : 
- `"['bus'~'yes']['psv'~'yes']" ` that gives me the roads where both can access, but does'nt include those where only one can access
- `"['bus'!~'.*|no']"` that gives me the roads where the tag bus does'nt exist or where buses are'nt allowed. but I only can play withe the 'bus tag' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OSMnx does not include a customizable union operator for multiple keys in its querying apparatus, your best bet is indeed to make two queries then combine them. But you should use the `compose` function to do so:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

place = 'Marseille, France'
G1 = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', retain_all=True, custom_filter='["bus"="yes"]')
G2 = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', retain_all=True, custom_filter='["psv"="yes"]')
G = nx.compose(G1, G2)
print(len(G1), len(G2), len(G)) #784 141 855
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239377/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883614/7321942

Comment: is it still the case that the `custom_filter` doesn't include customizable unions?

Comment: Yes as of April 2023.