# How to use multiple tags in custom_filter?

Tags: osmnx

I am trying to add a union of tags in the `custom_filter` parameter, however, OSMNX seems to not recognize the union syntax as described in the [Overpass QL Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Union). How can I add several tags to filter on inside the `custom_filter` parameter?

My goal is to use a filter like:
`customBikeFilter = '(["bike"~"designated"]; ["highway"~"cycleway"];)'`

I expect to get all the roads tagged as `["bike"~"designated"]` **OR** `["highway"~"cycleway"]`. Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSMnx : how to provide more complex feature into the custom\_filter parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699216/osmnx-how-to-provide-more-complex-feature-into-the-custom-filter-parameter)

Comment: Bit unfortunate that this is the only feasible solution but it will do. Thanks for the reply!