# Extracting a network of streets and rivers using OSMnx

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm looking to construct a network of both streets and rivers using OSMnx

I was trying this:

```
country_graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon=drc_boundary.geometry.iloc[0], simplify=True, retain_all=True, custom_filter='["waterway"~"river"]["highway"~"primary|trunk"]')
```

But this would give an error:

```
EmptyOverpassResponse: There are no data elements in the response JSON
```

Is there a way to do so using the custom filter, or should I get the street network and water network separately and then combine them together?

Comment: I think extracting the two as separate layers is the way to go. Also you may want to try the `ox.graph_from_file` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying for ways that match both conditions: waterway=True *and* highway=primary|trunk. No ways match both those conditions. You instead need to get the waterways first, then the highways second:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
point = -3.399514, 17.402937
G1 = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=20000, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True,
                         custom_filter='["waterway"~"river"]')
G2 = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=20000, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True,
                         custom_filter='["highway"~"primary|trunk"]')
G = nx.compose(G1, G2)
print(len(G1), len(G2), len(G))  # 12 6 18
```

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239377/7321942
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883614/7321942
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720802/7321942